# Unable to retrieve element of desired XPATH using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just get started with web scraping and I'm using BeautifulSoup (Python) for the job. I would like to get some property data for a sample webpage for testing. The code started as following,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

page = "http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1630-Amalfi-Dr-Pacific-Palisades-CA-90272/20546602_zpid/"
response = requests.get(page)
soup = Soup(response.text)

# now, I would like to get the price for sale price of the apartment 
# the element in the HTML DOM is as following, 
# <span class="" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1464168312477_3548">$12,895,000<span class="value-suffix"></span></span>
# The XPath of the element, //*[@id="yui_3_18_1_1_1464168312477_3548"]

# I write the code as following,
value = soup.select('span#yui_3_18_1_1_1464168312477_3548')
print value
```

I don't get any result. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I opened the webpage in browser. Opened page source and searched for "yui_3_18_1_1_1464168312477_3548", there were zero results. Are you sure this web page have span with this id?

Comment: It is not in the source, it is dynamically generated

Comment: Okay, I'm not very proficient in web scraping, indeed, this is the first time I'm doing this. So, my question is, say, if I would like to the for sale price and address of the property, how can I get those info ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the source in the console which is not the same as the source you get back from requests, the `span id="yui_3_18_1_1_1464170172533_3087"` is dynamically generated so you will need to use something like [*selenium*](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Unfortunately the id is also unique each visit so we cannot use that, what is consistent is the parent div so we can get the first span inside the parent with the `main-row home-summary-row` class using a *css selector*:

```
In [4]: from selenium import webdriver
In [5]: dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()

In [6]: dr.get("http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1630-Amalfi-Dr-Pacific-Palisades-CA-90272/20546602_zpid/")
In [7]: span = dr.find_element_by_css_selector('div.main-row.home-summary-row span')
In [8]: print(span.text)
$12,895,000
```

I used [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) for headless browsing, you can use Firefox or Chrome if you prefer, all the info is in the links.

Actually looking at the source again we can do the same using bs4, the id is the only thing dynamically generate so if we forget the id we can get the price:

```
In [26]: soup.select_one("div.main-row.home-summary-row span").text
Out[26]: u'$12,895,000'
```

An even better way is to use the meta tags to get lots of info:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

page = "http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1630-Amalfi-Dr-Pacific-Palisades-CA-90272/20546602_zpid/"
response = requests.get(page)
soup = Soup(response.text,"lxml")
metas = soup.select("meta")
```

Now if we look at what metas returns:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(metas)

[<meta content="on" http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control"/>,
 <meta charset="unicode-escape"/>,
 <meta content="View 31 photos of this $12,895,000, 7 bed, 10.0 bath, 10500 sqft single family home located at 1630 Amalfi Dr, Pacific Palisades, CA 90272 built in 2015. MLS # 16-103696." name="description"/>,
 <meta content="Zillow, Inc." name="author"/>,
 <meta content="Copyright (c) 2006-2014 Zillow, Inc." name="Copyright"/>,
 <meta content="none" name="msapplication-config"/>,
 <meta content="ALL" name="ROBOTS"/>,
 <meta content="NOYDIR" name="ROBOTS"/>,
 <meta content="NOODP" name="ROBOTS"/>,
 <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"/>,
 <meta content="black-translucent" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"/>,
 <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"/>,
 <meta content="#3366b8" name="msapplication-TileColor"/>,
 <meta content="http://www.zillowstatic.com/static/images/logos/zillow-logo-win8-tile.png" name="msapplication-TileImage"/>,
 <meta content="/8Me6HBNZX/rt2n5/y1Lo3ZIrkcvkTBimqviTDiurR4=" name="verify-v1"/>,
 <meta content="7cb4abe457d82ae8" name="y_key"/>,
 <meta content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>,
 <meta content="Zillow Real Estate, Rentals, and Mortgage" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="The most trafficked website about home sales and rentals, with real estate values for almost every U.S. home. 1,000,000 listings that you won't find on MLS." itemprop="description"/>,
 <meta content="http://www.zillowstatic.com/static/images/social/share_thumbnail.png" itemprop="image"/>,
 <meta content="691f1bfccade71b5-c065751219a379dd-g64cedb67f5ea020a-a" name="google-translate-customization"/>,
 <meta content="202692,878610170,662000799,100001769907023,10716009,769244502,10716649,503322863" property="fb:admins"/>,
 <meta content="172285552816089" property="fb:app_id"/>,
 <meta content="zillow_fb:home" property="og:type"/>,
 <meta content="1630 Amalfi Dr, Pacific Palisades, CA 90272" property="og:zillow_fb:address"/>,
 <meta content="7" property="zillow_fb:beds"/>,
 <meta content="10" property="zillow_fb:baths"/>,
 <meta content='For sale: $12,895,000. Stunning brand new Contemporary Cape Cod Estate in Palisades Riviera by Huntington Estate Homes w/ 7 beds, 10 baths, + office in 10,500 sq ft on an 18,590 sq ft lot. Soaring ceilings, magnificent chandelier, &amp; floating staircase create a grand entrance w/ glass wine cellar, formal living &amp; dining rooms. Floor plan flows openly between gourmet kitchen, family room, &amp; patio with a set of disappearing Fleetwood Pocket doors. Fireplaces in living, family, &amp; master suite add warmth to the contemporary feel, &amp; detailed wood paneling &amp; coffered ceilings enhance quality of design throughout. Master suite opens completely to sweeping ocean views &amp; private patio. Lower level feats. Old Hollywood style theater w/130" screen, surround sound, stadium seats, floor-to-ceiling suede panels, exercise pool, spa, gym, office, guest beds, open air patio, &amp; elevator access to take you from floor to floor. Perfect for entertaining - outdoor BBQ, seating, &amp; saltwater pool/spa complete this elegant estate.' property="zillow_fb:description"/>,
 <meta content="http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1630-Amalfi-Dr-Pacific-Palisades-CA-90272/20546602_zpid/" property="og:url"/>,
 <meta content="Pacific Palisades Home For Sale" property="og:title"/>,
 <meta content="http://photos2.zillowstatic.com/p_d/IS5ypcj39edbdc1000000000.jpg" property="og:image"/>,
 <meta content='For sale: $12,895,000. Stunning brand new Contemporary Cape Cod Estate in Palisades Riviera by Huntington Estate Homes w/ 7 beds, 10 baths, + office in 10,500 sq ft on an 18,590 sq ft lot. Soaring ceilings, magnificent chandelier, &amp; floating staircase create a grand entrance w/ glass wine cellar, formal living &amp; dining rooms. Floor plan flows openly between gourmet kitchen, family room, &amp; patio with a set of disappearing Fleetwood Pocket doors. Fireplaces in living, family, &amp; master suite add warmth to the contemporary feel, &amp; detailed wood paneling &amp; coffered ceilings enhance quality of design throughout. Master suite opens completely to sweeping ocean views &amp; private patio. Lower level feats. Old Hollywood style theater w/130" screen, surround sound, stadium seats, floor-to-ceiling suede panels, exercise pool, spa, gym, office, guest beds, open air patio, &amp; elevator access to take you from floor to floor. Perfect for entertaining - outdoor BBQ, seating, &amp; saltwater pool/spa complete this elegant estate.' property="og:description"/>,
 <meta content="https://videos.zillowstatic.com/production/07a58eebcafbfe833b92f17945131f2e251b5fe5/mp4_600k_landscape_z1/mp4_600k_landscape_z1.mp4" property="og:video"/>,
 <meta content="https://videos.zillowstatic.com/production/07a58eebcafbfe833b92f17945131f2e251b5fe5/mp4_600k_landscape_z1/mp4_600k_landscape_z1.mp4" property="og:video:secure_url"/>,
 <meta content="640" property="og:video:width"/>,
 <meta content="video/mp4" property="og:video:type"/>,
 <meta content="360" property="og:video:height"/>,
 <meta content="238648973530.apps.googleusercontent.com" name="google-signin-clientid"/>,
 <meta content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" name="google-signin-scope"/>,
 <meta content="http://zillow.com" name="google-signin-cookiepolicy"/>,
 <meta content="summary_large_image" name="twitter:card"/>,
 <meta content="@Zillow" name="twitter:site"/>,
 <meta content="@Zillow" name="twitter:creator"/>,
 <meta content="1630 Amalfi Dr" name="twitter:title"/>,
 <meta content="Stunning brand new Contemporary Cape Cod Estate in Palisades Riviera by Huntington Estate Homes w/ 7 beds, 10 baths, + office in 10,500 sq ft on an 18,590 sq ft lot. Soaring ceilings, magnificent chandelier, &amp;amp; floating staircase create a grand entrance w/ glass wine cellar, formal living &amp;amp; dining rooms. Floor plan flows openly between gourmet kitchen, family room, &amp;amp; patio with a set of disappearing Fleetwood Pocket doors. Fireplaces in living, family, &amp;amp; master suite add warmth to the contemporary feel, &amp;amp; detailed wood paneling &amp;amp; coffered ceilings enhance quality of design throughout. Master suite opens completely to sweeping ocean views &amp;amp; private patio. Lower level feats. Old Hollywood style theater w/130&amp;quot; screen, surround sound, stadium seats, floor-to-ceiling suede panels, exercise pool, spa, gym, office, guest beds, open air patio, &amp;amp; elevator access to take you from floor to floor. Perfect for entertaining - outdoor BBQ, seating, &amp;amp; saltwater pool/spa complete this elegant estate." name="twitter:description"/>,
 <meta content="http://photos2.zillowstatic.com/p_d/IS5ypcj39edbdc1000000000.jpg" name="twitter:image"/>,
 <meta content="1630 Amalfi Dr, Pacific Palisades, CA 90272" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="USD" itemprop="priceCurrency"/>,
 <meta content="$12,895,000" itemprop="price"/>,
 <meta content="34.060605" itemprop="latitude"/>,
 <meta content="-118.501625" itemprop="longitude"/>]
```

We can pull the price and other info using the attributes:

```
In [22]: soup = Soup(response.text,"lxml")

In [23]: soup.select_one("meta[itemprop=price]")["content"]
Out[23]: '$12,895,000'

In [24]: soup.select_one("meta[name=twitter:description]")["content"]
Out[24]: 'Stunning brand new Contemporary Cape Cod Estate in Palisades Riviera by Huntington Estate Homes w/ 7 beds, 10 baths, + office in 10,500 sq ft on an 18,590 sq ft lot. Soaring ceilings, magnificent chandelier, &amp; floating staircase create a grand entrance w/ glass wine cellar, formal living &amp; dining rooms. Floor plan flows openly between gourmet kitchen, family room, &amp; patio with a set of disappearing Fleetwood Pocket doors. Fireplaces in living, family, &amp; master suite add warmth to the contemporary feel, &amp; detailed wood paneling &amp; coffered ceilings enhance quality of design throughout. Master suite opens completely to sweeping ocean views &amp; private patio. Lower level feats. Old Hollywood style theater w/130&quot; screen, surround sound, stadium seats, floor-to-ceiling suede panels, exercise pool, spa, gym, office, guest beds, open air patio, &amp; elevator access to take you from floor to floor. Perfect for entertaining - outdoor BBQ, seating, &amp; saltwater pool/spa complete this elegant estate.'
In [27]: soup.select_one("meta[itemprop=latitude]")["content"]
Out[27]: '34.060605'
In [28]: soup.select_one("meta[itemprop=longitude]")["content"]
Out[28]: '-118.501625'
In [29]: soup.select_one("meta[property=og:zillow_fb:address]")["content"]
Out[29]: '1630 Amalfi Dr, Pacific Palisades, CA 90272'
```

Comment: Can you write some sample code for me to get started ? I will then accept your answer. I would like to get the sale price and address of the property.

Comment: yep, just doing it now, there is more fun with the page as the id is unique each call so we need to find a way around that.

Comment: This is really helpful, I highly appreciate this answer.